# "Domain wall" from continuous symmetry

Tags: cosmology, universe, symmetry-breaking

For a discrete $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry for instance, in some patches of the Universe, it can spontaneously breaks $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and goes in the "right" minimum, while in some others patches it can go in the "left" minimum. This leads to domains walls. Do we have the equivalent of domain walls for continuous symmetries, let's say $U(1)$, because it can go to the minimum $v$ as well as any of the other minima $v\times \exp(i\theta)$?

Comment: is this classical field theory or quantum field theory?

Comment: I strongly suspect this is all about classical fields, from the tag « cosmology ». Personally, I’m more interested in the classical definition.

Comment: Classical field theory

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, when $U(1)$ is spontaneously broken we have [cosmic strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_string) (aka vortices), which can be global or local depending on whether the $U(1)$ is global or local symmetry. Then there are [magnetic monopoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%27t_Hooft%E2%80%93Polyakov_monopole) which arise when a non-abelian symmetry $G$ is spontaneously broken to a smaller symmetry group $H$, such that the quotient space $G/H$ (which is the vacuum manifold of the theory) has non-trivial second homotopy group $\pi_2(G/H)$. For example, when $G=SU(2)$ and $H=U(1)$ the quotient $G/H$ is isomorphic to two-sphere ($S^2$), and
$$\pi_2(SU(2)/U(1))=Z~~~({\rm integers})$$
If $\pi_2(G/H)$ is trivial -- no monopoles.

Similarly, the existence of cosmic strings can be inferred from non-trivial first homotopy group $\pi_1$ of $U(1)$ which is also given by integers. This classification of topological defects can be generalized as
$$
\pi_n(G/H)
$$
which basically represents how many times (if at all) $S^n$ wraps around the vacuum manifold $G/H$. $\pi_1$ tells us about cosmic strings, $\pi_2$ about point defects, or monopoles, $\pi_3$ classifies so-called cosmic textures. There are also higher-dimensional generalizations of these defects.

In addition, another way to think about topological defects, is by looking for non-contractible $S^n$ spheres. In the presence of a cosmic string you cannot continuously contract a circle to a point (if the circle surrounds the string), in the presence of a monopole you cannot contract a two-sphere around the monopole, and so on.

Comment: this is not correct, as far as I can see. $\pi_1$ has little to do with this -- SSB of su(n) leads to dynamical excitations too, yet $\pi_1 SU=0$. These excitations are not topological, they are dynamical. e.g., pions, etc.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform "these excitations are not topological" - exactly. The question was about topological defects, as I understand (so my answer is about those), which can be classified as I wrote, by their winding numbers (topological charges) given by the homotopy groups.

Comment: Domain walls are not topological defects. Top. defects, indeed, are classified by homotopy groups. Domain walls are not. (I guess they are technically classified by $\pi_0$, but not in any useful way).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform "Domain walls are not topological solitons" - I disagree with this statement

Comment: Good, because that is not the statement I made :-) A top. defect is, by definition, an operator $U(\Sigma)$ that depends on some region of spacetime $\Sigma$ topologically, i.e., $U(\Sigma)$ is invariant under $\Sigma\to\Sigma+\delta\Sigma$. Domain walls are not invariant under these deformations. To leading order, the dynamics of DW are given by the Nambu-Goto action, namely they tend to minimize their area. Under a deformation, the DW picks up an energy $T\delta\Sigma$, with $T$ the tension. DW are very much not top. defects.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform  I accidentally changed "defect" to "soliton" :)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform in any case, I'm not familiar with that definition, where is it from? In my mind topological defects are just solitons.

Comment: The DW certainly can move and deform, but it cannot disappear. Once it’s there, it cannot be removed unless it collides with another one (an anti-soliton).  Intuitively, a DW is certainly a topological defect.

Comment: @Cham or unless there is a lower-energy vacuum. Then DW is metastable and can collapse by tunnelling. I guess this kind of DW can be classified into its own category

Comment: @Kosm The usual reference for topological defects is https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.5148 (incidentally, this paper indirectly answers the question in the OP, see the second paragraph on page 4).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I guess that's one way to define defects=operators=observables

Comment: @Kosm Yes, I did some googling and it seems that the cosmology community uses a different terminology from the QFT community, hence the confusion. The two groups use the words "topological defects" with different meanings, so forget the words. For discrete $G$, DW are classified by $\pi_0(G/H)$, here we agree. I don't understand what role the higher homotopy groups $\pi_{i\ge1}$ play here. They classify higher co-dimension objects, correct, but what does that have to do with the question in the OP? The question is what happens when you make $G$ continuous. No?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I understood the question in terms of (classical) field theories, as asking about the generalization of DW for continuous $G$, as stable solutions to field equations

Comment: @Kosm fair enough, I was thinking about QM, in fact the tag that I added may be wrong. I will remove it and ask OP whether they care about classical field theory or QFT. Cheers!